# Not overriding draw

Tags: android, view, drawing

Okay so far when I have used SurfaceView I would override the draw method and then call it from a seperate thread. However, recently I tried to not override it but simply make all my canvas drawing calls in a custom method, and it worked. I would just do all my drawing the same way but instead of all the code being in overridden draw method, I would just put it all in another method and it worked anyways. So whats the point of overriding anything? I honestly still don't know how all the drawing works behind the scenes as its not explained...

Answer (score 0):

For `SurfaceView` as you noticed yourself it makes no difference. There's no point of overriding `draw` and then calling it yourself from the separate thread.

The `SurfaceView` only have the method there because it inherits it from the `View` class, but because you're, in a separate thread, acquiring the lock to the canvas, drawing and then releasing, it doesn't matter if you pass it to the `draw` method, if you use directly on the thread `run` or some other `Runnable`

Maybe one could argue that it's more organised (and do never underestimate the importance of a well organised code), but it's not a necessity.

Comment: Okay thanks! Could you tell me where I could learn how android draws stuff behind the scenes, as in what methods are called automatically and such?

Comment: I use this extension on my browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin and it adds a "View Source" link on the official docs page, so anywhere in "http://developer.android.com/reference/" I can always check the source code.